# Knockout custom bindings for popular libraries?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have searched for knockout js custom bindings for jquery, bootstrap, anmiate.css etc .
But no good result :( !
Do you know any good libraries (maybe your own implementation) .
I think there should(must) already be a large number of custom bindings for at least popular libraries .
But it seems like no body is written a single line of custom bindings out there !!!

Comment: This is off-topic the way it's phrased, but what are you looking for specifically? Show/hide animations with knockout?

Comment: yes ! that would be a great start :)

Comment: @user1575632 there are examples of show/hide animations at the KnockoutJS site (look under 'custom bindings')

Comment: thanks but what i am looking for is a collection of general bidings for jquery , boostrap and maybe animate.css libraries . those samples are great but i dont want to reinvent the wheel if someone already have written custom bidings specially for these libraries .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend:

- Bootstrap: http://billpull.github.io/knockout-bootstrap/
- jQuery UI: http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/

I don't know animate.css, and since it's CSS, I doubt there's custom bindings for it.